# Docker Cluster with Kafka can't establish a connection with a client container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka

I get the following error message from the client application:

> Connection to node 1002 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

Node 1002 is the correct broker id, which means that it is able to find it, but I don't understand why the connection itself can't be established when the client application worked when not running on a container.

Docker-Compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 127.0.0.1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  app:
    image: someuser/someimage
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    environment:
       KAFKA_CONNECTION: kafka:9092
    depends_on:
      - kafka
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      group-id: tdp-loggers
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
    bootstrap-servers: ${KAFKA_CONNECTION}

tdp:
  topic-name: advice-topic
  messages-per-request: 10
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8080

COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./
RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline

COPY src ./src

CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
```

Comment: Try setting the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` to the container's name (`kafka`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Turing85 posted answer, I had to change the

> KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME

variable from a static IP Address of 127.0.0.1 to kafka.

Comment: I did not post an answer, I requested you to try it since I was not sure that it fixes the problem...